# Bot Framework region

Tags: botframework, region

Is the Bot Framework deployed in any particular region?  I want to avoid any unnecessary latency when connecting my app service with the MBF, and if the MBF is only hosted in 1 region, North Europe for example, then I would also deploy my app service in North Europe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this answer off MS via other channels, in Nov 2017:

Bot Framework is hosted world-wide. Posts you make to the bot framework connectors are routed using traffic manager to the nearest datacenter to you (DNS wise). We're additionally adding more Azure regional deployments; 2 in Australia, one in brazil, and additional deployments in West Europe and East Asia respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Was just checking for any update on this. Last what I found is:
https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/1413
(Nov 2016, Bot Framework just release to North Europe and SE Asia, apart from both US coasts).
Some posts there also confirm that when the bot is moved to West US then delay is gone.
Would be good to have a clear statement from Microsoft and rules of routing to particular BF region depending on end user location, wouldn't it?